# Rails simple_form create form when column type is JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a model (`FooBar`) with three columns:

```
Foo -> String
Bar -> JSON
Baz -> String
```

I want to create a form for this model

Bar has default attributes of: `{zing: {}, zaz: {}, laz: {}}`

I would like to have the following inputs:

```
f.input :foo
f.input :zing
f.input :zaz
f.input :laz
f.input :baz
```

I tried to do this using fields_for and passing in each key and converting it to a symbol:

```
bar.each do |k,v|
f.input k.to_sym
end
```

but the error I'm getting is that FooBar has undefined method of :zaz

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
f.simple_fields_for :bar do |bar_f|
  bar.each do |k,v|
   bar_f.input k.to_sym
  end
end
```

Don't forget to allow the parameters in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, HashSerializer
  store_accessor :preferences, :blog, :github, :twitter
end
```

And then you will have access to blog, github and twitter just as if they were normal properties in the model and your form is going to look something like this:

```
= simple_form_for(@user, html: { class: "form" }) do |f|
  = f.input :blog
  = f.input :github
  = f.input :twitter
```

You have more info in this link! https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-inputs-for-key-value-hash-attributes

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Set @temp variable

```
@temp = FooBar.new
@temp.data = {zing: "", zaz: "", laz: ""}
```

This code works for me

```
<%= simple_form_for @temp do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :data do |data_f| %>
    <% @temp.data.each do |k,v| %>
      <%= data_f.input k.to_sym %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget about permission params

```
params.require(:temp).permit(data: [:zing, :zaz, :laz])
```

Comment: How to show the input box with value. It does not populate the input box with the value

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to define accessors, you could do something like:

```
= simple_form_for(@foo_bar) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :bar do |bf|
    = bf.input :zing, input_html: { value: f.object.bar[:zing] }
    = bf.input :zaz, input_html: { value: f.object.bar[:zaz] }
    = bf.input :laz, input_html: { value: f.object.bar[:laz] }
```

You would need to initialise bar with `{}` in your controller